# Can not run oracle SQL embed in java by using intellij

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea

Currently, I'm trying to embed some oracle SQL statements into java project and I'm using IntelliJ as compiler. The problem is, I have set ojdbc7.jar into Intellij,
[image]

but my computer still showing me errors like this:

`Error: Cannot find or load the main class employee`

`Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Employee (wrong name: employee)`

And what drives me crazy is, if I run commands:

`javac -cp ojdbc7.jar employee.java`

`java -cp ojdbc7.jar;. employee`
on cmd, the program will run successfully. But no matter how I try, employee.java cannot be compiled on intellij. And the cause of the error is as I mentioned above.
This is the beginning of my code:

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
import oracle.sql.*;

public class employee
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        String user, pass, snum, namer;
        int enumber;
        
        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.print("Enter your username: ");    // Your Oracle ID with double quote
        user = "my_oracle_Account";                   //console.readLine();  
        System.out.print("Enter your password: ");    // Password of Oracle Account
        //console.readPassword();
        pass = "my_password";

        // Connection
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
        OracleConnection conn = 
            (OracleConnection)DriverManager.getConnection(
             my_url,user,pass);
        
        System.out.println("Program starts.");
        // do something...
    }
}
```

the codes have no problem, and also please don't focus on command `java -cp ojdbc7.jar;. employee` I know sometimes ";. " should be ":. ".
Previously, there are also other errors like `concole is null`

You can see that I have commented out console.readLine(). Because when I run it, the program won't stop and wait for input.
This seems relate to path problem but I cant solve it.
How to make intellij run the employee successfully? I need to debug the program, pls help me.

Comment: This problem seems to have nothing to do with Oracle. Can you run a simple "hello world" program in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: yes, I can. The IntelliJ works well.

Comment: As the error message says your class name should start with upper case E

Comment: Show the project structure and run configuration you are using, like https://i.imgur.com/K345xl2.png

Answer (score 0):

OK, problems solved. As Jens said after I change the file name from employee to Employee it works correctly. But why? Actually I download this codes from my professor's website so I never doubt its correctness! Such a stupid error...And why it could be run successfully on cmd? Just a nuance on "E" and "e". Last night I try to do this but because I have declared another class named Employee in the same Project file so I skipped this method. Such a stupid error and ... me!
Btw, thank you guys a lot.